# React Router Dom nested routing, or how to pass a slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass a slug to a header component without having to include the header to each and every subcomponent.

My code looks like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <Header />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container>
          <Grid item xs={false} md={2} />
          <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={IntroPage} />
              <Route exact path="/:slug" component={StartPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/index" component={StartPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/player" component={PlayerPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/game" component={GamePage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/scoreboard" component={ScoreboardPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/controller" component={ControllerPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/settings" component={SettingsPage} />
              <Route path="/:slug/credits" component={CreditsPage} />
              <Route component={PageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={false} md={2} />
        </Grid>
        <ToastContainer autoClose={3000} hideProgressBar />
      </Grid>
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Footer />
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What I want is the Header component to know what slug was chosen in one of the routes within the Switch.

Is there a possibility to do this with for example nested routing?

Best regards,
Patrick

---

Edit:

This is my Header component btw:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params.slug)
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState();

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, { [classes.appBarShift]: open })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography>Placeholder Banner</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        className={classes.drawer}
        classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          <ListItem component="a" href="/" button key="start">
            <ListItemIcon>
              <HomeIcon fontSize="large" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Start</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem component="a" href="/game" button key="game">
            <ListItemIcon>
              <SportsEsportsIcon fontSize="large" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Game Setup</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem component="a" href="/player" button key="player">
            <ListItemIcon>
              <PersonIcon fontSize="large" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Player Setup</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem component="a" href="/settings" button key="settings">
            <ListItemIcon>
              <SettingsIcon fontSize="large" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Settings</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem component="a" href="/credits" button key="credits">
            <ListItemIcon>
              <InfoIcon fontSize="large" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Credits</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I want to give the links the ability to include the slug. For example `href=/game` needs to be `href=:slug/game` then.

And please be aware that header is loaded before the switch.

---

Edit2:

At least this:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  const {match, location, history} = props
  console.log(match)
  console.log(location)
  console.log(history)

....

export default withRouter(Header);
```

will give me access to the location which has the slug. But this appears to not be the cleanest way. Also match.params does not hold the slug, even with `withRouter` export. Why is that?

## My solution until I know better (Not working)

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  const { location } = props;
  let pathname = location.pathname
  let slug = pathname.split("/")
  console.log(slug[1]);

....


export default withRouter(Header);
```

This will cause that the url gets confused after a few clicks cause location will be concatenated again and again resulting ins urls like /myslug,game,player,...

## Final solution

Well I got the final solution from below which is:

Wrap the Header in its specific location into Route

```js
        <Grid item>
          <Route path={["/:slug", "*"]} component={Header} />
        </Grid>
```

Then access props.match.params in Header component:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params)
```

this will give:

```js
slug: "game"
```

Comment: Use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) or get the params from the currently matched route's [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) prop from the `Router`.

Comment: `const Header = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params.slug)` This is not working though. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

Comment: `Header` isn't rendered by a `Route` so you need to use the `useParams` hook, or the `withRouter` HOC to get the match params from the closest `Router`. Or simply render the `Header` into a match all `Route`, i.e. `<Route component={Header} />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `Header` isn't being rendered on a route so it doesn't have access to any of the route-props, specifically, the route parameters. It also needs to be rendered on a Route that matches a path that specifies the "slug" route parameter.

## Solution

Render the `Header` into a `Route` that specifies both a match all path ***and*** a path that can match with a slug. Order matter so specify the path with slug first so it can be matched before less specific routes (same as the rules for the `Switch`).

```
<Route path={["/:slug", '*']} component={Header} />
```

Comment: Option 1 and 2 will give me undefined. UseParams() can just render splug which is in router, but header isn't. Option 2 will not have slug in the props.match (I guess for the same reason). Option 3 will not work as it breaks my grid layout.

Comment: Presumably your `Router` is wrapping your `App`, if this isn't the case then please add the important details about where your `Router` is as this is the component that hold the route data, i.e. the "slug" route parameter.

Comment: It does in fact wrap the app: `    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>` in index.js

Comment: This will omit rendering my main content though! And render behaviour differs depending on position in switch.

Comment: @PatrickHener Updated answer with how the `Header` component can access the slug. `Route` components don't have much, if any, visual aspect, so if by rendering your `Header` into a `Route` messes up the grid layout it's probably because you've components making assumptions about their parent components. I assume it's simply trying to inherit some CSS.

Comment: `Switch` only matches and returns first match.... don't put the `Header` in your `Switch` if you want it to always render. Wrapping `Header` in `Route` is simply for the sake of accessing the route props.

Comment: Oh okay I get that. So I wrapped it at it's original position. But then again, useParams() will give me an error.

Comment: Oh well, I can then access it via props.match.params. This is the solution!

Comment: What is/was the error you were seeing by using the hook? If in a route then both the hook and match prop *should* work roughly the same.

Comment: Error was `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` at Line where there was `const {slug} = useParams()`

Comment: Ohh *facepalm* me dumb! I imported it from react not from react-router-dom. Now useParams is working, too.

Comment: @PatrickHener I see. I was going to say you need to be on React v16.8+ and on the v5 version of react-router-dom to use the hooks.

Comment: Anyone know why is it called slug?

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz It's just a named path parameter. It's called "slug" here because that is what it was declared as with `"/:slug"`. It could just as easily have been named any other valid Javascript identifier, e.g. `"/:id"`, `"/:placeholder"`, `"/:name"`, etc. I believe the term "slug" has leaked over from *certain* libraries that use it as an identifier placeholder, e.g. `"/books/:slug"`, `/teams/:slug"`, etc, all likely from trivial code examples where the route paths have only a single path parameter. This quickly breaks down though when paths container more dynamic segments.

Answer (score 0):

Try using useParams() to get the slug.

Comment: That is not working as Header is loaded before the switch. There is no slug yet when Header is rendered.

Comment: Might want to check out withRouter then. I think that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try do like this:

```
<Route 
   exact 
   path='/:slug/player' 
   render={(props) => <PlayerPage {...props}/>}
/>
```